# jhipster input datetime-local show only date

Tags: jhipster

I have and app generated using jhipster.
I have "Person" module, where each people has a "Birthdate" column.
All works fine but the app shows the birthdate including time and I wan't to show that like this.
I need to show only the date like this "dd/mm/yyyy"

Can any one help me please?

This is my code:

input id="field_fechaNacimiento" type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="fechaNacimiento" [(ngModel)]="persona.fechaNacimiento"
                       required/>

persona.fechaNacimiento = 01/09/2018T00:00

The front shows: 01/09/2018T00:00

I need to show: 01/09/2018

Date without time

Comment: Start by showing your code, the expected output from some input, the output you get, etc.

Comment: Please show the jdl definition of your entity.

Comment: entity Persona {
    nombre String required maxlength(200),
    apellidos String required maxlength(100),
    fechaNacimiento Instant required,
    calleNumero String maxlength(200),
    colonia String maxlength(200),
    cp String maxlength(10),
    ciudad String maxlength(100),
    correo String maxlength(100),
    telefono String maxlength(20),
    celular String maxlength(20),
    activado Boolean required,
    fechaCreacion Instant required,
    fechaUltimaModificacion Instant required
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `LocalDate` instead of `instant`?
Here are some other types:
https://www.jhipster.tech//jdl/#types_and_constraints

Comment: great! this is what I where looking for, in the front end, 
change: <input type="datetime-local" name="fechaNacimiento" [(ngModel)]="persona.fechaNacimiento"/>
for  <input type="text" name="fechaNacimiento" ngbDatepicker  #fechaNacimientoDp="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="persona.fechaNacimiento"/>